# demers cartogram

Tags: d3, cartogram

How do you make a demers cartogram from a shapefile/topojson/geojson? I have tried scapetoad and indiemapper and i can not duplicate what you find on the links below.

http://graphics.latimes.com/2012-election-results-california/#/us_house 
http://elections.nytimes.com/2012/ratings/electoral-map

I am looking to duplicate the square representations of the states exactly as you would find it on a map.   I can not find a software that will do that for you without manually doing it in adobe illustrator. 
Any ideas?

Comment: Technically those are cartograms, but the software you are looking at creates Areal Cartograms, where the size of a zone is proportional to the variable of interest (population etc).

Comment: All I need is the software that creates Area Cartograms.

Comment: Actually you don't since the examples you link to aren't areal cartograms - each block is the same size regardless of the size of the district it represents.

Comment: Look at the NY times example. The blocks are not the same size. They are directly proportional to the electoral votes. The LA version , I could see doing that one in a drawing program but it would be nice if there was a way to do both from a shapefile to cartogram conversion software.

Answer (score 3):

This is what a Cartogram does:

normal map
[image: normal map]
<sub>(source: [choros.ch](https://scapetoad.choros.ch/images/Suisse.gif))</sub>

cartogram
[image: cartogram]
<sub>(source: [choros.ch](https://scapetoad.choros.ch/images/SuisseA.gif))</sub>

You can try ScapeToad to make a cartogram
https://scapetoad.choros.ch/

What you are trying to do is create a grid pattern with areal cartograms - each block is the same size regardless of the size of the district it represents.

What your trying to do looks like

![aerial cartogram] (https://www.gislounge.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/04/frenchwikimap.png)

Try one of the tools listed below

https://www.gislounge.com/area-cartograms-explored/

Mapresso
http://www.mapresso.com/

Protovis
http://mbostock.github.io/protovis/